# Pass GET variable into On Click function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to pass my `Amount` variable from the link to the Pay function inside the On Click, but I can't. How can I do?

**Link:** example.tld/index.php?amount=20

**Code:**

```
<?php $amount = $_GET['amount']; ?>
<button onclick="pay(<?php echo $amount; ?>)">Pay</button>
```

Comment: Should work.  If you view source you should see `onclick="pay(20)"`  What happens/doesn't happen?

Comment: What if `$_GET['amount']` isn't set?

Comment: Try to see if $_GET['amount'] returns anything. echo $_GET['amount'] or var_dump($_GET['amount']);

Comment: This looks like it should work. What does "can't" mean? Debug your code and tell us more precisely what goes wrong.

Comment: PHP passes amount to a JavaScript function pay(), that is case sensitive. Shall you  use Pay() instead of pay() as used within onclick() callback ?